# How do I test a middleware that requires sessions in Django properly?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-middleware

I'm trying to figure out how to test middleware in django. The middleware I'm writing logs in a user under certain conditions (if a key sent in email is valid). So obviously I'm dependent on `django.contrib.auth` and `django.contrib.sessions`.

I'm running into problems testing the login portion. I'm making a request like this:

```
user = User.objects.create_user('user', 'user@example.org', 'password')
key = LoginKey.objects.create(user=user)
request = self.factory.get('/', data={'auth_key': key.hash}) # self.factory is a RequestFactory()
self.middleware.process_request(request) # self.middleware is MyMiddleware()
```

That fails due to the session not being set. So next, I wrote a little snippet in my test class:

```
def make_session(self, request):
    SessionMiddleware().process_request(request)
```

and that fails due to `'User' object has no attribute 'backend'`. I'm not sure on the meaning of that, but I suspect I need to run all the middlewares I have installed.

I don't really want to make a fake view for this just to run a middleware, but I can't see another option at this point.

So I just wanted to know, before I have to chase this rabbit all the way down the hole, is there a way of doing this that doesn't require as much duct tape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the test client for this. That will ensure that the middleware is run and the session keys created.

```
response = self.client.get('/?auth_key=%s' % key.hash)
self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_authenticated()) # for example
```

Comment: As I said, this app is just a middleware and a model. Wouldn't I have to add views, urls, etc to get that? I'm trying to keep it as minimal as possible.

Comment: Er, I suppose I didn't say that. Whoops.